# RavenDB schema migrations

Tags: ravendb, database-migration

I want to change my RavenDB "schema" and perform a Migration at startup of ASP.Net MVC web app.

[Patching](http://ayende.com/blog/157185/awesome-ravendb-feature-of-the-day-evil-patching) mechanism seems to fit the purpose, and I try to use it like:

```
store.DatabaseCommands.UpdateByIndex(
    "Raven/DocumentsByEntityName",
    new IndexQuery
    {
        Query = "Tag:LogEntries",
    },
    new ScriptedPatchRequest()
    {
        Script = @"
                    this.IsDeleted = false;
                "
    }
).WaitForCompletion();
```

The problem is, that Patch will simply throw exception if the index is stale. But I really need to be sure that Migration was performed before continue to run the app. Are there better alternatives than wrapping it in something like:

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        RunPatch();
        break;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

With Entity Framework or NHibernate (FluentMigrations) it's easy to write a Migration class, assign a Version to it, and then needed Migrations will be executed automatically in proper order.

Is there a similar built-in mechanism for Raven? Or any known best-practices for that?

Comment: Why do you need such a huge setup for this? I keep some migration scripts in a separate console app and run them when I need to against my local/remote stores. Usually you only need to do this once. Anything else is overkill IMHO unless you're doing this a TON. You can use Stream API to easily change stuff, store them, then save changes afterwards. For one-off stuff, memory isn't an issue.

Comment: There is this, as well: http://ayende.com/blog/66563/ravendb-migrations-rolling-updates Furthermore for the *ByIndex commands, there's an overload to "allowStale" you can set to `true`. If you want to be sure it runs, you could wait for non-stale indexes (but understand if there's lots of updates happening, that could be a long time). For your specific use case above, I'd write a one-off script to run to ensure it hits every doc at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an answer, albeit 6 years after you asked!  There is the RavenMigrations project on GitHub here:

https://github.com/migrating-ravens/RavenMigrations

This is a migration framework for RavenDB, similar to those that you will find for relational databases.